# Django 1.11: "global name 'user' is not defined"

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a survey app - you create a Survey and it saves the Response. It's registered in Django Admin. I can see the Survey and submit a Response. When I click **Response** in Admin, I get the following error:

> ValueError at /admin/django_survey/response/
> Cannot query "response 5f895af5999c49929a522316a5108aa0": Must be "User" instance.

So I checked the SQL database and for `django_survey_response` I can see that there is a response, but the column `user_id` is `NULL`.

I suspected that there's an issue with my *Views* and/or *Forms* and I'm not saving the logged in User's details, so I've tried to address that.

However, now I get

> NameError at /survey/1/
>
> global name 'user' is not defined

How do I resolve this? I want the form to save **Response** with the logged in user's ID.

The Traceback:

> django_survey\views.py

```
def SurveyDetail(request, id):
    survey = Survey.objects.get(id=id)
    category_items = Category.objects.filter(survey=survey)
    categories = [c.name for c in category_items]
    print 'categories for this survey:'
    print categories
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ResponseForm(request.POST, survey=survey) <.........................
        if form.is_valid():
            response = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/confirm/%s" % response.interview_uuid)
    else:
        form = ResponseForm(survey=survey)
        print form
```

> django_survey\forms.py

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # expects a survey object to be passed in initially
    survey = kwargs.pop('survey')
    self.survey = survey
    self.user = user <.........................
    super(ResponseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.uuid = random_uuid = uuid.uuid4().hex  
    # add a field for each survey question, corresponding to the question
    # type as appropriate.
    data = kwargs.get('data')
```

It might be worth noting that previously, instead of `user`, the model's field was called `interviewee`. I changed this and ran migrations again.

I am also using **userena**.

Comment: So what is that `user` supposed to be? Where is it defined? How is it supposed to be getting into that method?

Comment: As soon as I read that it all made sense. Thanks for your help as always Daniel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message in this instance is python trying to tell you that you are attempting to access a variable `user` that has not been defined in the scope of  your method.

Let's look at the first few lines of the `__init__()` method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # expects a survey object to be passed in initially
    survey = kwargs.pop('survey')
    self.survey = survey
    self.user = user
```

We can see where the `survey` variable is defined: `survey = kwargs.pop('survey')`. It is passed into the form as a keyword argument and extracted in the forms `__init__`. However underneath you attempt to do the same  thing with `user` but haven't actually defined it above. The correct code would look like:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # expects a survey object to be passed in initially
    survey = kwargs.pop('survey')
    user = kwargs.pop('user')
    self.survey = survey
    self.user = user
```

However, this still won't work because we aren't passing the `user` variable to the form via kwargs. To do that we pass it in when we initialise the form in your `views.py`. What isn't clear is what user object you are expecting to pass in. the `request.user`? or does the `Survey` object have a user attribute? in which case you would not need to pass user in and would just use `survey.user` etc.

django_survey\views.py

```
def SurveyDetail(request, id):
    survey = Survey.objects.get(id=id)
    category_items = Category.objects.filter(survey=survey)
    categories = [c.name for c in category_items]
    print 'categories for this survey:'
    print categories
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ResponseForm(request.POST, survey=survey, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            response = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/confirm/%s" % response.interview_uuid)
    else:
        form = ResponseForm(survey=survey, user=request.user)
        print form
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick (although you have a slight mistake, it should be: `else: form = ResponseForm(survey=survey, user=request.user)`. I understand what I was doing wrong now.

Answer (score 1):

In your view when you initialize your form you need to pass it the user (current user in this case)? similar to this `form = ResponseForm(request.POST, survey=survey, user=request.user)`. Then in the `__init__` of your form pop the user object `user = kwargs.pop('user')`. I believe that will resolve your issue.